# CakePHP serving cached controller actions, regarding to user agent

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I can cache controller actions in my CakePHP 2 application by using [CacheHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html). And this helper provides me to select cache duration, "nocache" parts of page etc.

But is it possible to serve cached actions regarding to User agent of the visitor. For instance I plan to show cached page to crawlers/bots, but construct the page if visitor is not bot. I don't want to select which parts of the page will be cached / nocached. Taking the page as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that will work for you:

Assume you are using the latest version of cakephp add this to your core.php
bellow to the line where you configure Cache.check

Example and Code:

```
/**
 * Enable cache checking.
 *
 * If set to true, for view caching you must still use the controller
 * public $cacheAction inside your controllers to define caching settings.
 * You can either set it controller-wide by setting public $cacheAction = true,
 * or in each action using $this->cacheAction = true.
 *
 */
    // Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
    $UAs = array(
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11'
    );

    if (in_array(env('HTTP_USER_AGENT'), $UAs)) {
        define('USE_CACHE', '1 hour');
        Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
    } else {
        define('USE_CACHE', false);
        Configure::write('Cache.check', false);
    }
```

$UAs refers to the user agents of bots

This is a sample controller that you can use to test the code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class HomeController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'Home';

    public $uses = array();

    public $helpers = array(
        'Cache'
    );

    public $cacheAction = USE_CACHE;

    public function index() {}

}
```

Comment: Switching USE_CACHE to TRUE and FALSE will delete old cache files, won't it?

Comment: No, it will deleted only expired cached files.
To flush the entire cache is recommended to deleted it manually or use clearCache()

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html